# Python regex to find text that contains the pattern dot number dot

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I wish to find patterns in a large file where a line fulfills this basic criteria: "1.2" (that is, number dot number)

It should also return true in the following cases: "1.2.2" or "1.2.a" or "texttext1.2.3text text" or "text2.3textext"

I have the following query written as part of a `python3` program that imports the `re` module:

```
re.compile(r"^\d*[.]?\d*$")
```

However, the problem is that it also returns true for just numbers such as '112231'.

How do I fix my regex?

Comment: Maybe all you need is `r"\d\.\d"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to match a digit followed with a dot and then another digit.

Use

```
r"\d\.\d"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RszKsg/1).

In Python, to check if a string matches the pattern use

```
m = re.search(r"\d\.\d", s)
if m:
    print("Matched!")
```

A note on Unicode: `\d` in Python 3.x regex will also match all Unicode digits, like those (examples):

```
0٠۰߀०০੦૦୦௦౦೦൦๐໐༠០᠐᧐᱐꘠０1١۱߁१১੧૧୧௧౧೧൧๑໑༡១᠑᧑᱑꘡１2٢۲߂२২੨૨୨௨౨೨൨๒໒༢២᠒᧒᱒꘢２3٣۳߃३৩੩૩୩௩౩೩൩෩๓໓༣៣᠓᧓᱓꘣３4٤۴߄४৪੪૪୪௪౪೪൪๔໔༤៤᠔᧔᱔꘤４5٥۵߅५৫੫૫୫௫౫೫൫෫๕໕༥៥᠕᧕᱕꘥５6٦۶߆६৬੬૬୬௬౬೬൬๖໖༦៦᠖᧖᱖꘦６7٧۷߇७৭੭૭୭௭౭೭൭෭๗໗༧៧᠗᧗᱗꘧７8٨۸߈८৮੮૮୮௮౮೮൮๘໘༨៨᠘᧘᱘꘨８9٩۹߉९৯੯૯୯௯౯೯൯෯๙໙༩៩᠙᧙᱙꘩９
```

To avoid that, pass the [`re.A` or `re.ASCII` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.A) to the [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) or [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) methods. Or, use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

Comment: The user also said they wanted to match variations of that pattern. "It should also return true in the following cases: "1.2.2" or "1.2.a" or "texttext1.2.3text text" or "text2.3textext""

Comment: @emsimpson92 Exactly, they all contain that pattern.

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought they were looking for a full match.

Comment: @emsimpson92 BTW, your [`\w+(?:\.\w+)+`](https://ideone.com/1uCRxq) pattern matches `_._`, `s.s` and even `ⴰ.ⴰ` in Python 3.x `re`. Shorthand character classes are Unicode aware by default in Python 3.x regex.

Comment: yeah, I removed it